# Retrieve info between paragraph tags with feedparser

Tags: python, rss, feedparser

I've been reading through the documentation for feedparser and haven't been able to find a solution to this: I would like to retrieve only the string between `<p></p>`. An example of an excerpt from a feed I'd like to retrieve this from is:

`<img alt="Dawsons" height="259" src="http://i.cbc.ca/1.2703554.1405073659!/fileImage/httpImage/image.jpg_gen/derivatives/16x9_460/dawsons.jpg" title="Kathy Dawson and her daughter Emily Dawson, 18, now have a complaint before the Alberta Human Rights Commission over a sexual education course Emily had to take last year. " width="460" />                <p>The Edmonton Public School Board has said it will tell teachers not to use an anti-abortion centre to teach part of its sexual education curriculum, after a McNally high school student filed a human rights complaint over what she was taught.</p>`

Note: this is from the RSS feed at `http://www.cbc.ca/cmlink/rss-topstories`

which I retrieved with

```
for item in cbc.entries:
    print item.summary
```

I know I could easily write something to manually parse through and return only what I want but is there a way feedparser can do it for me?

Comment: if you just want the text beautifulsoup can get it quite easily

Comment: Thanks! Was hoping not to involve beautiful soup but it seems like a simple and effective solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything in the docs about parsing using tags but beautifulsoup can get the text;

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get("http://www.cbc.ca/cmlink/rss-topstories")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
print [''.join(s.findAll(text=True)) for s in soup.findAll('p')]

[u"Search teams are returning to the home of Kathy and Alvin Liknes today for another sweep of the property, close to two weeks after the couple and their grandson Nathan O'Brien were discovered missing in Calgary.", u"Israel widened its air assault against the Gaza Strip's Hamas militants on Saturday, hitting targets that included a mosque the Israeli military said was being used to conceal rockets. Meanwhile, there are reports Hamas has launched rockets at Tel Aviv.", u'The Sunni militant group ISIS, which wants to create an Islamic state spanning Iraq and Syria, has issued a recruitment video using the image and words of a dead Ontario man who had become a jihadist and joined the fighting in Syria.', u'A Hamilton-area man\u2019s dashcam may have saved him a pricey car insurance payout \u2013 and maybe even from falling victim to an insurance scam, an industry expert says.', u'Tommy Ramone, a co-founder of the seminal punk band the Ramones and the last surviving member of the original group, has died, a business associate said Saturday.', u"During high-stake police interrogations and on seemingly meaningless online dating profiles, some people find themselves lying. So, how can you tell if someone isn't telling you the truth?", u"Israeli strikes in Gaza have led to sleepless nights and anxious Palestinian children, CBC's Derek Stoffel reports from a refugee camp in Gaza City.", u'Saskatchewan Premier Brad Wall has been a vocal proponent of abolishing the Senate. With the Prime Minister now under pressure to fill vacancies in the upper chamber, Wall argues that not appointing new senators might be the way to get rid of the institution.', u"Bassist Charlie Haden, who helped change the shape of jazz more than a half-century ago as a member of Ornette Coleman's groundbreaking quartet and liberated the bass from its traditional rhythm section role, has died. He was 76.", u"Tracy Morgan has sued Wal-Mart over last month's highway crash that seriously injured him and killed a fellow comedian.", u'Buying pot is normally a subtle affair, but not for Mike Boyer, who camped out to become the first person to legally purchase marijuana in Washington state.', u"Monika Platek, CBC's lead producer for social media during the World Cup, looks at some of the standout moments so far from the 2014 World Cup", u'Our weekly round-up of remarkable photos includes scenes from Brazil, Spain, Germany, India and elsewhere around the world.', u'The European Union said on Saturday that it has extended sanctions to cover 11 leaders of the pro-Moscow rebellion in eastern Ukraine.', u'The Edmonton Public School Board has said it will tell teachers not to use an anti-abortion centre to teach part of its sexual education curriculum, after a McNally high school student filed a human rights complaint over what she was taught.']
```

You could combine both:

```
import feedparser
d = feedparser.parse("http://www.cbc.ca/cmlink/rss-topstories")
soup = BeautifulSoup("".join([item.summary for item in d.entries]))
print [''.join(s.findAll(text=True)) for s in soup.findAll('p')]
[u"Search teams are returning to the home of Kathy and Alvin Liknes today for another sweep of the property, close to two weeks after the couple and their grandson Nathan O'Brien were discovered missing in Calgary.", u"Israel widened its air assault against the Gaza Strip's Hamas militants on Saturday, hitting targets that included a mosque the Israeli military said was being used to conceal rockets. Meanwhile, there are reports Hamas has launched rockets at Tel Aviv.", u'The Sunni militant group ISIS, which wants to create an Islamic state spanning Iraq and Syria, has issued a recruitment video using the image and words of a dead Ontario man who had become a jihadist and joined the fighting in Syria.', u'A Hamilton-area man\u2019s dashcam may have saved him a pricey car insurance payout \u2013 and maybe even from falling victim to an insurance scam, an industry expert says.', u'Tommy Ramone, a co-founder of the seminal punk band the Ramones and the last surviving member of the original group, has died, a business associate said Saturday.', u"During high-stake police interrogations and on seemingly meaningless online dating profiles, some people find themselves lying. So, how can you tell if someone isn't telling you the truth?", u"Israeli strikes in Gaza have led to sleepless nights and anxious Palestinian children, CBC's Derek Stoffel reports from a refugee camp in Gaza City.", u'Saskatchewan Premier Brad Wall has been a vocal proponent of abolishing the Senate. With the Prime Minister now under pressure to fill vacancies in the upper chamber, Wall argues that not appointing new senators might be the way to get rid of the institution.', u"Bassist Charlie Haden, who helped change the shape of jazz more than a half-century ago as a member of Ornette Coleman's groundbreaking quartet and liberated the bass from its traditional rhythm section role, has died. He was 76.", u"Tracy Morgan has sued Wal-Mart over last month's highway crash that seriously injured him and killed a fellow comedian.", u'Buying pot is normally a subtle affair, but not for Mike Boyer, who camped out to become the first person to legally purchase marijuana in Washington state.', u"Monika Platek, CBC's lead producer for social media during the World Cup, looks at some of the standout moments so far from the 2014 World Cup", u'Our weekly round-up of remarkable photos includes scenes from Brazil, Spain, Germany, India and elsewhere around the world.', u'The European Union said on Saturday that it has extended sanctions to cover 11 leaders of the pro-Moscow rebellion in eastern Ukraine.', u'The Edmonton Public School Board has said it will tell teachers not to use an anti-abortion centre to teach part of its sexual education curriculum, after a McNally high school student filed a human rights complaint over what she was taught.']
```

Answer (score 0):

I just import re and do

```
justtheParagraphs = re.findall("<p>(.*?)</p>", yourfeed.entries.content).group(1)
```

hope this is a sensible example. you can use search for just the first one but I find myself wanting all `"<p>(.*?)</p>"`   and then displaying the second one [.group(1)].